# Rails & Kaminari: Pagination showing duplicate results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I have a rails app using Kaminari for pagination. For some reason, on some pages, some of the last results of the last page are carried over to the first results of the next page.

Here's my controller:

```
 def available
    trailers = Trailer.most_recent.released.order("movies.imdb_rating desc").where("movies.imdb_rating IS NOT NULL")
    @trailers = trailers.page(params[:page]).per(18)
end
```

Scopes in the Trailer model:

```
 scope :most_recent, -> {
    where('NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM trailers b2 WHERE b2.movie_id = trailers.movie_id AND trailers.is_short_trailer = FALSE AND
    b2.is_short_trailer = FALSE
    AND (b2.published_at > trailers.published_at OR b2.published_at = trailers.published_at AND b2.id < trailers.id))').
    where(show: true).
    where(is_short_trailer: false)
  }

  # gets all trailers that have at least one release
  scope :released, -> { 
    joins(movie: :releases).where("movies.release_date > ?", 25.years.ago)
  }
```

And the view:

```
<div class="trailers-container">
  <%= render @trailers %>
</div>


<div class="pagination">
  <%= link_to_next_page(@trailers, 'Next') %>
</div>
```

So when I click on the 'Next' page, sometimes it's fine, but sometimes I will see duplicate trailers (actual duplicates, I checked the IDs).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that `movies.imdb_rating` is an integer then this ordering clause may well return results in different order: `order("movies.imdb_rating desc")`

Imagine if all the movies had a rating of 8 exactly. The movies could come back in any order and be correct.

You need to add another field to sort by.  Perhaps title (so rating, then title) or release year or even just id.  Ex: `order("movies.imdb_rating desc, movies.title")`

Comment: Wow, I totally missed that. Thank you so much, spent way too long on this.

Comment: I have a similar issue, and your assuming is right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a `joins` with your `has_many :releases` via `:movie`, that will create multiple records, one for each release joined with.

You probably want a `uniq` in that scope:

```
scope :released, -> { 
  joins(movie: :releases).where("movies.release_date > ?", 25.years.ago).uniq
}
```